# how to grep part of the content from a string in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

For example when filtering html file,
if every line is in this kind of pattern:

```
<a href="xxxxxx" style="xxxx"><i>some text</i></a>
```

how can I get the content of `href`, and how can I get the text between `<i>` and `</i>`?

Comment: Use xmlstarlet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Does xmlstarlet work with HTML too?

Comment: @Gumbo: You'd have to shove it through HTML Tidy first, but that's not too big a deal. And it's more a matter of the option not existing, not the underlying libraries being unable to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cat file | cut -f2 -d\"

FYI: Just about every other HTML/regexp post on Stackoverflow explains why getting values from HTML using anything other than HTML parsing is a bad idea. You may want to read some of those.  [This one for example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

If href is always the second token separated by space in a,ine then u can try

grep "href" file | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d'=' -f2

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using xmlstarlet (optionally with tidy):

```
# extract content of href and <i>...</i>
echo '<a href="xxxxxx" style="xxxx"><i>some text</i></a>' |
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//a" -v @href -n -v i -n

# using tidy & xmlstarlet
echo '<a href="xxxxxx" style="xxxx"><i>some text</i></a>' |
tidy -q -c -wrap 0 -numeric -asxml -utf8 --merge-divs yes --merge-spans yes 2>/dev/null | 
xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" -T -t -m "//x:a" -v @href -n -v . -n
```